# what to do with missing value for ANOVA?

Tags: anova, missing-data

A researcher sent me a data set. 
The Y is intensity.
X is A,B,C,D,E 5 treatments. 
A-D treatments all have 5 samples.
However, E treatment only has 4 samples.
When I ask the researcher about it, she said that because the 5th sample for treatment E has many values that are less than 500(which means too low), so she just deleted it.

However, in my opinion, the 5th sample in treatment E should be treated as outlier. Otherwise, it will become a unbalanced design. Right?

Another question is that if we decide to delete the sample at last, then will the degree of freedom change as well?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to describe your data and the study in greater detail. Are you able to recover the "deleted" data or is it lost? Why <500 is considered "too low" - are such values impossible or they just do not fit the theory? Do you know why the values are so low (e.g. measurement equipment malfunction)? Finally, deleting data that does not fit your theory is most basic example of "lying with data".

Comment: The issues Tim mentions will be important considerations - but even if you do end up deleting the value rather than doing something else with it, why is there a particular problem with an unbalanced design?